# My php code is not working fine. Doesn't check if data matches

Tags: php

I have my `pin.php` as:

```
<?php //connection $db_host="localhost"; $db_username="root";
$db_password="";


$connection =
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");

if (!$connection){ die("database connection failed: ".
mysql_error()); }

session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 120, ]);   //Start a new session (2 minutes)

?> <html> <head> <title>Check Result</title> </head> <body> Check
Result<br /><br /> <?php $dbname = "db";
    $db_sel=mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection);
    if(!$db_sel) {
        echo "<h1>Unable to Connect to the Database</h1><hr />";
        exit();
    }

// Check submit button click 


if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))  { if (!empty($_POST['uname']) &&
!empty($_POST['pass'])) {    $serial =
stripslashes(trim($_POST['serial']));   $pin =
stripslashes(trim($_POST['pin']));

   $sign = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE serial='$serial' AND
pin='$pin'");
       $no=mysql_num_rows($sign);  //if username and password matches    if($no!=0)
    { 

        $_SESSION['serial']=$serial;        $_SESSION['pin']= $pin;

        $logintimes=mktime();

        $ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            //Redirects the user to the password protected page
    header("Location: result.php");
         exit();

        }   else{ // if invalid serial/pin  echo "Invalid";

 } }  else{ // if empty on submit    echo "empty";//empty”;  }  } ?>
<form action="print.php" method="post"> Serial Number: <input
type="text" name="serial" value="" class="style3" size="18"/><br />
PIN: <input type="hide" name="pin"  class="style3" size="18"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button"  />
</form>         </body> </html>
```

and my result.php as:

```
<?php
           session_start([    'cookie_lifetime' => 120, ]); if(isset($_SESSION['serial']) && ($_SESSION['pin'])) {   ?>
    <h3>Welcome</h3> <div> This is your    result...<br /> <?php
        $logintimes=mktime();
        $ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        echo $logintimes;   echo $ipaddress; ?> </div> <?php    session_destroy(); } else { //Redirects the user to the login page
    if    he is not logged in header("Location: index.php"); } ?>
```

On submit, it's still accessing result.php without checking if `serial=$serial` AND `pin=$pin`

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Are these 2 variables really commented out like this `<?php //connection $db_host="localhost"; $db_username="root";`

Comment: Why is this `if($no!=0)` commented out? It seems to be crucial to the function logic. Just a paste error?

Comment: We should start a bitcoin collection and spend @Wisdom a good training camp in Sibiria to get the least principles of programming style taught. What do you think? :p

Answer (score 0):

Guys I looked into this a little. tried to clean it up so its more readable, and I would suggest at least templating out the page and use replace('tag',function()) method to enter data into the template.

---

```
<?php //connection $db_host="localhost"; $db_username="root";
$db_password="";

$connection = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");

if (!$connection){ 
    die("database connection failed: ".mysql_error()); 
}

session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 120, ]);   //Start a new session (2 minutes)
    ?> <html> <head> <title>Check Result</title> </head> <body> Check Result<br /><br /> <?php
    $dbname = "db";
    $db_sel=mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection);
    if(!$db_sel) {
        echo "<h1>Unable to Connect to the Database</h1><hr />";
        exit();
    }

    // Check submit button click 

    if( isset($_REQUEST['submit']))  { 
        if (!empty($_POST['uname']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {    
            $serial = stripslashes(trim($_POST['serial']));   
            $pin    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['pin']));
            $sign   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE serial='$serial' AND pin='$pin'");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sign, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
                $_SESSION['serial'] = $serial;        
                $_SESSION['pin']    = $pin;
                $logintimes         = mktime();
                $ipaddress          = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                //Redirects the user to the password protected page
                header("Location: result.php");
                exit();
            } // if success above will exit, else get to the below error note.
                echo "Invalid";
            } 
        } else { // if empty on submit    
            echo "Please enter you name or password FooL";//empty”;  
        }  
    } 
    ?><form action="print.php" method="post"> Serial Number: <input type="text" name="serial"  value="" class="style3" size="18"/><br /> PIN: <input type="hide" name="pin"  class="style3" size="18"/><br /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button"  /> </form></body> </html>
```

I didn't test it, but you can see I replaced the n$no with a row pull, the point you need to understand is the row count will be zero because you haven't yet pulled the row, the point is still at the start.